# How do I print off a count button onto a label and save it forever? Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionviewcell

I have a button that when it's pressed it counts how many times it is pressed. The problem is that as soon as the app quits the data is lost, in addition, the user has no way to see how many clicks the button has.

I have a label on my Collection View Cell which I want to hold the number of taps the button has received (button is also on my Collection View Cell). I need to make sure each cell doesn't load their cell Vote count to the same button counter.

I am using Firebase on my app, in case I need to store the data in Firebase and call it back.

Below is my Collection View Cell with the button and the label inside of it.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase


class PostCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var postImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var authorLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var likeLabel: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var likeBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var unlikeBtn: UIButton!


    @IBOutlet weak var thisLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var thisButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var thatLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var thatButton: UIButton!

    var counterThis = 0

    var counterThat = 0
    @IBAction func thisButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        counterThis += 1

    }

    @IBAction func thatButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        counterThat += 1

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var thisVoteCounter: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var thatVoteCounter: UILabel!

   // @IBOutlet weak var thisVoteLabel: UILabel!
   // @IBOutlet weak var thatVoteLabel: UILabel!

    var postID: String!
    var thisString = String()
    var thatString = String()






    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.thisLabel.sizeToFit()
        self.thisLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.thatLabel.sizeToFit()
        self.thatLabel.layoutIfNeeded()



    }
}
```

I need a way to display the counting function, make sure the data saves and make sure all of the Collection View Cells button clicks do NOT go into the same counting button.

Any and all help is appreciated!!

UPDATE:

```html
import UIKit
import Firebase


class PostCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var postImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var authorLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var likeLabel: UILabel!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var likeBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var unlikeBtn: UIButton!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var thisLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var thisButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var thatLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var thatButton: UIButton!
    
    

    
    var counterThis = 0
    
    var counterThat = 0
    
    var counterThisString = Int()
    
    var counterThatString = Int()
    
    
    cell.thisButtonCounter.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.thisButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

    func thisButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let point : CGPoint = (sender as AnyObject).convert(CGPoint.zero, to: postCell)
        let indexPath = postCell!.indexPathForItem(at: point)
        let cell = postCell!.cellForItem(at: indexPath!) as! PostCell
        counterThis += 1
        cell.thisLabel.text = "\(counterThis)"
    }
    
    
    
   /* @IBAction func thisButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        counterThis += 1
        print(counterThis)
        
        counterThis.int = counterThatString
        
        return
    }
    
    @IBAction func thatButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        counterThat += 1
        
        print(counterThat)
        
        counterThat.int = counterThatString
        
        return
    }
 */
    
    @IBOutlet weak var thisVoteCounter: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var thatVoteCounter: UILabel!
    
   // @IBOutlet weak var thisVoteLabel: UILabel!
   // @IBOutlet weak var thatVoteLabel: UILabel!
    
    var postID: String!
    var thisString = String()
    var thatString = String()
    
    
 
    
    
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.thisLabel.sizeToFit()
        self.thisLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.thatLabel.sizeToFit()
        self.thatLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
        
        
   
    }
```

This is my code now and I'm still not figuring out the problem. Can you please write out what I need to put to my make code work?

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Do you need to save large data or just somewhat?

Comment: Now I am just trying to get my thisButtonTapped function to print off the counts it has in it to a label on the same cell. I don't need to save it yet

Comment: you can easily do that by cellForItem delegate method

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Can you show it to me please? I've tried searching it up but it doesn't seem to click in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I know whatever I am posting is not the answer related to question but after discuss with @priM he ask me for the help with another query

you need to add the target in *cellForItemAt*

```
cell.btnCounter.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
```

you can catch the action with following and make sue you need to change the label text inside the action method.

```
func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let point : CGPoint = (sender as AnyObject).convert(CGPoint.zero, to: collectionView)
        let indexPath = collectionView!.indexPathForItem(at: point)
        let cell = collectionView!.cellForItem(at: indexPath!) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
        counterThis += 1
        cell.lblCellItemName.text = "\(counterThis)"
    }
```

Hope this help you

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not understanding

Comment: what you aren't getting?